# Passing a state to another component so I can render a list?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-props, setstate, react-component

I am trying to render a list, I am doing my central component in a Class, and with a  form and some inputs I want to setState of the class so I can use those values to render a list element, nevertheless it is not working, I can't even log the state's properties after the click, how can I manage to use those values on the inputs to render list elements? Should I use hooks instead?

```
class TASKMANAGER extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            name: "",
            description:"",
            priority: "urgent",
        }
        
    
    }

     
    

    handleTitleChange = event => {
        this.setState( {
            name: event.target.value
        })
        };

    handleDescriptionChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            description: event.target.value
        })
        };

    handlePriorityChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            priority: event.target.value
        })
        };
        
    
    handleClick() {
            console.log(this.state);
        }
            

    

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
             <div className= 'task-form'>  
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Name your task!</label>
                    <input type= 'text' id='task-title' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleTitleChange} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Description?</label>
                    <textarea id='description' value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleDescriptionChange}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Priority?</label>
                    <select value={this.state.priority} onChange={this.handlePriorityChange}>
                        <option value='urgent'>Urgent</option>
                        <option value='regular'>Regular</option>
                        <option value='Can wait'>Can wait</option>
                    </select>    
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>PRESS</button>
            </form> 
            </div>
            <div className='list-items'>
                <ul>
                
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>   
            )
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [**PRESS**] button will trigger a form **submit** event, which will **refresh** the page by default.
 Your log code will be never seen.

Your codes are almost ok.
Just add **preventDefault()** in the **handleClick()** function.

```
    handleClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code and removed form submit event as you can store the list in state even without form submit to render the list in same page

```
  class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     name: "",
     description: "",
     priority: "urgent",
     list: [] // added the list to add above values
    };
  }
 .......
 ........
handleClick = (event) => {
 this.setState((state) => {
  const list = [
    ...state.list,
    {
      name: state.name,
      description: state.description,
      priority: state.priority
    }
  ];
  return {
    list
  };
 });
```

};

And in render, to display as list

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>
    .....
    .....
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>PRESS</button>
     </div>
    <div className="list-items">
      <ul>
        {this.state.list.map((list, index) => (
          <p key={index}>
            Name: {list.name} || Description: {list.description} ||
            priority: {list.priority}
          </p>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code as you gave it but it didn't render, I basically implmented something similar only that the handleClick is a push method to the state.list and the  variable that contains the list element is inside the render method, it is now working but it doesn't render when i press the button, I need to erase one character from the input in order to render, you know what can be?